# Facebook Share button (add "via page" to share)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

Is there a way to include "via my facebook page" when sharing a blog post on my website? Usually when someone clicks the share button, they share with their personal accounts, but could I also add a link to the facebook page as a "via my-page" when someone clicks the share button on my blog site (wordpress)?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on share button you can choose that:

[image: Select menu]

Then you can even choose which page exactly, if you have more than one.